# Stuck on Ubuntu

Tags: graphics

Please check this picture:

[image]

Any one have same problem while changing the desktop wallpaper(by right click) or by playing any movie or anything else?

Any solutions?
My PC has the Asus M2N68-AM SE2 motherboard with NVIDIA GeForce 7025 / NVIDIA nForce 630a

Comment: So this happens when you change the wallpaper or play a video ? Sounds GPU related, what is your GPU ? Do you have the drivers for it ? Please edit your question to include your PC specs and GPU driver. Also what Ubuntu version ? When did this start, new install ?

Comment: My PC has the Asus M2N68-AM SE2 motherboard with NVIDIA GeForce 7025 / NVIDIA nForce 630a

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia drivers ?

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -k` to the question

Comment: @markkirby for linux i don't any drivers for nvidia

Comment: @kos which output?

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-346-updates`, enter password, wait for install and reboot. Please post back if it works or not.

Comment: @markkirby is it really a graphic program?  Mean after this error of screen there is only one option to work is restart   till then no mouse no keyboard nothing work?   Is it really a graphic program?   I am new to Ubuntu      don't know much more :) so please help

Comment: That is my logic here anyway, but I can't see your computer, I can only go on what you have said, I might be wrong, but installing a GPU driver won't hurt and is highly recommended as in Windows.

Comment: @markkirby no i don't mean that  the kb and mouse work well    i mean they don't effect any thing after this error       ohhk i will try to install driver as u suggest and will give u feedback about it :)   ty for ur support

Comment: Im confused now, you said "after this error of screen there is only one option to work is restart" I took this as "All I can do is restart my PC" So I thought the whole computer was locked on that crashed screen until you restarted it, am I wrong ?

Comment: @markkirby i mean to say nothing on screen expect this error and u cannot use any shortcut etc nothing    only way is to work is restart

Comment: @markkirby hey.... This is saying unable to locate package nvidia-346-update     now what should i do?

Comment: Open the dash (top left) and find the `software & updates` app, go to the `additional drivers` tab and install the latest stable version for your card.

Comment: @markkirby there is nothing in the list

Comment: Try adding this PPA then look again `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && apt-get update`

Comment: @markkirby Thank you thank you thank you so much sir :D my problem is sloved :D all things working well till now :D ty so much again sir :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was a lack of a GPU driver for an older more obscure onboard nvidia chipset (NVIDIA GeForce 7025 / NVIDIA nForce 630a ).

Installing a driver from PPA fixed this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && apt-get update
```

Then open the additional drivers app from the dash and select the appropriate `proprietary` driver.